# Implementing an accumulating function using Conduit

Tags: haskell, conduit

I am exploring the possibility to use the Conduit package in order to implement complex event processing in Haskell. As an example, I would like to implement an accumulating function using Conduit.

Starting from:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack script --resolver lts-8.12 --package conduit-combinators
{-# LANGUAGE ExtendedDefaultRules #-}
import Conduit

trans :: Monad m => ConduitM Int Int m ()
trans = do
    mapC (* 2)

main :: IO ()
main = runConduit $ yieldMany [1..10] .| trans .| mapM_C print
```

I get:

> 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20

How can I modify `trans` so that it yields

> 1 3 6 10 15 21 28 36 45 55

instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`scanlC`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-1.3.0/docs/Conduit.html#v:scanlC), which is an "analog of `scanl` for lists", does almost what you want. I say "almost" because `scanlC` asks for and yields an initial "seed" value, which you don't need nor want (cf. the difference between `scanl` and `scanl1`). That being so, you will need to explicitly feed the first streamed value as the seed:

```
trans :: Monad m => ConduitM Int Int m ()
trans = await >>= maybe (return ()) (scanlC (+))
```

(The -- clearly inferior -- alternative would be having `trans = scanlC (+) 0` and using `dropC 1` in the next step of the pipeline to get rid of the `0`.)

Comment: typo in the alternative: trans = scanlC (+) 0 ... I actually like the alternative better because the additional 0 is a small price to pay compared to the simplicity of the solution

Comment: @Christophe Thanks; typo fixed. I think the main disadvantage of the alternative is that you have to change the rest of the pipeline to get the correct behaviour, while with the other solution the changes only affect the step that does the transformation you want to happen. If you need this kind of scan in multiple places, you can always define `scanl1C f = await >>= maybe (return ()) (scanl1C f)` and then have e.g. `trans = scanl1C f`.